# How to show determinant of a derivative is unequal to $0$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

The question is: let $y=f(x)$ and $x=g(y)$ be each other's inverses with both functions from $R^2\rightarrow R^2$, both being $C^1$ functions. Show $det(df(x))\neq0$, $\forall x\in R^2$.
I don't really know how to approach this, I realise derivatives can be expressed as matrice's. Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe
\begin{align}
x =g(f(x)).
\end{align}
Then by chain rule, we have
\begin{align}
Dx = D[g(f(x))]  \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ I = Dg(f(x))Df(x).
\end{align}
Hence $Df(x)$ is invertible, i.e. $\det(Df(x)) \neq 0$.

Comment: Why does that prove Df(x) is invertible?

Comment: Because $Df(x)$ has an inverse.

Comment: How did you show that?

Comment: When I say $Dg(f(x))Df(x) = I$, you could also check the left inverse by considering $y = f(g(y))$.

Comment: I am sorry I'm being thick, but why does that show that the derivative has an inverse? Or that that is it's inverse? I am not very proficient at multivariable derivatives

Comment: Well. We say a matrix $A$ is invertible if there exists $B$ such that $AB = BA = I$ where $I$ is the identity matrix. In this case, we have that $Dg(f(x))$ is a matrix such that $Dg(f(x))Df(x) = I$.

Comment: I don't see how $Dx=D[g(f(x))]$ implies $I=Dg(f(x))Df(x)$